# Determined or not?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits

the function $\dfrac {2x}{3x-\sqrt{x} }$ is not derterined for values of $x$ equale or samller than zero, though when I take the limit $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac {2x}{3x-\sqrt{x} }$ the output is zero as though the function gets the value $(0,0)$ at that point, even though we know that's not the case....how come?

Comment: The function cannot get the value (0,0) because it's not determined for x=0. However the limit does exist and equals 0. What exacly is your question?

Comment: You could ask the same question about $\dfrac{x}{x}$.

Answer (score 5):

It is actually the whole point of defining limits. The reason is to study the behaviour of functions in messy and difficult positions. If you know the [definition of a limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) you will note that the actual value of the function at the point in which the limit is evaluated is redundant. Say we require the value of the limit of a function at the point $a$. The function need not be defined at $a$ necessarily. But if the limit $L$ exsists then what we need to make sure is the fact that $f(x)$ is arbitrarily close to $L$ when $x$ is arbitrarily close to $a$. For an exmple the function $ f(x) = \dfrac{x^2 - x}{x - 1} $ is nothing but the function $f(x) = x$ except for the point $x = 1$ where it is undefined. You will note that by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit we can prove the function is arbitarily close to $1$ when $x$ is arbitrarily close to $1$. That is all we need to assert that $\lim_{x \to 1}  \dfrac{x^2 - x}{x - 1} = 1$

Answer (score 2):

Limit can be defined at $x_0$ regardless of the value at $f(x_0)$. Indeed, the function has a limit, but it's not [continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) at $x_0$.

Also, consider this: [Classification of discontinuities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that while $x\to 0^+$, $x$ is not standing on $0$ on the real line. So we have $$x=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}, ~x>0$$ and are allowed to omit the irritating parts from numerator and denominator.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "irritating"?

Comment: @Elimination: I mean, we can remove some equal parts from num. and deno. of the fraction. They are two $\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps refresher on "removable discontinuities" would be helpful. http://www.drensplace.com/Math/Calculus/page0/page20/page37/page37.html shows 2 types of removable discontinuities, one with $f(a)$, on the other with $f(a)$ not defined.

A when calculating a limit at $a$, we are unconcerned about how it is defined at $a$. What is important is how the function behaves NEAR $a$ (sorry, was that too loud?).

A limit is really just a game. Suppose we suspect that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$. You get to pick a number $\epsilon\gt 0$. If I can pick a number $\delta\gt 0$ such that $L-\epsilon\lt f(x)\lt L+\epsilon$ whenever $a-\delta\lt x\lt a+\delta$ (except possibly at $x=a$, because $f(a)$ may be undefined), then I win a jellybean. If I can always win a jellybean, no matter what value you pick for $\epsilon$, then we say that $L$ is the limit.